# Why Array{Float64, N} cannot be a parameter of a function whose parameter is Array{Number, N}?

Tags: types, casting, julia, covariance

I found that `Array` in Julia is not covariant and subtypes of `Number` are not auto-converted to supertypes.

What I mean is, for example,

`head(a::Vector{Number}) = a[1]` or `head(a::Vector{Real}) = a[1]`

cannot execute `head([1, 2, 3])`,

whereas `head(a::Vector{T}) where {T <: Number} = a[1]` or `head(a::Vector{T}) where {T <: Real} = a[1]` can.

Is there a reason for this behavior in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this section in the manual: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1 which explains this. Note that there is a short form for `head(a::Vector{T}) where {T <: Number} =...` (which you can use unless you use `T` in the function body):

```
head(a::Vector{<:Number}) =...
```